# How to embed a Selenium WebDriver as a WPF control?

Tags: wpf, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to embed a `WebDriver` driver to a WPF window, similarly to the WPF's `WebBrowser` control?

Optionally, is there a way to use Selenium on the `WebBrowser` control itself?

---

So far, it's only possible to create a new `WebDriver` window, separate from any other WPF window in the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a slightly trick one ;)

As Selenium uses external applications (the browsers) most of the time there is no "native" solution like just integrating the Browser-UI in an app.

There are, however, Windows-specific APIs to achieve exactly that with WinForms.

> UnsafeNativeMethods.cs

```
private static class UnsafeNativeMethods {
        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
}
```

Basically the idea is to "wrap" the external browser within a usercontrol in your app.

> SeleniumHost.cs

```
    public void AttachDriverService(DriverService service) {
        //get the process started by selenium
        var driverProcess = Process.GetProcessById(service.ProcessId);

        //find the first child-process (should be the browser)
        var browserProcess = driverProcess.GetChildren()
                                .Where(p => p.ProcessName != "conhost")
                                .First();

        _BrowserHandle = browserProcess.MainWindowHandle;

        //set the parent window utilizing Win32-API
        UnsafeNativeMethods.SetParent(_BrowserHandle.Value, this.Handle);
        //handle moving/resizing of your appo to be reflected on browser
        UnsafeNativeMethods.MoveWindow(_BrowserHandle.Value, 0, 0, Width, Height, true);

        this.Resize += (sender, e) => {
            UnsafeNativeMethods.MoveWindow(_BrowserHandle.Value, 0, 0, Width, Height, true);
        };
    }
```

At last the extension used to enumerate child-processes via [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ProcessExtensions.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<Process> GetChildren(this Process parent) {
    var query = new ManagementObjectSearcher($@"
        SELECT *
        FROM Win32_Process
        WHERE ParentProcessId={parent.Id}");

    return from item in query.Get().OfType<ManagementBaseObject>()
           let childProcessId = (int)(UInt32)item["ProcessId"]
           select Process.GetProcessById(childProcessId);
}
```

and call the method like:

```
var host = new SeleniumHost();
var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service);
host.AttachDriverService(service);
```

When done, this solves the WinForms-Part. To integrate this in WPF you need to leverage [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx) to display the WinForms-Control.

Check out my fresh published [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/earloc/AppHost.Selenium) for further reference or directly leverage the [NuGet-Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppHost.Selenium.WPF).

Please bear with me, as those are very hot bits - so there sure will be bugs and further improvements to make in the future (like removing the chrome/border from the browser). Hopefully you can get the idea and/or maybe contribute on GitHub.

Comment: Hello @earloc, i found your library very helpful, but the problem is in your library the required .Net Framework is 4.6.2 and i want to use it in 4.5, could you please help me

Comment: Might give it a try. 
The lib consists of two nuget-packages. The WPF-package is really just a tiny wrapper around the WinForms-implementation (where the real magic happens). The WinForms-assembly targets net4.0, so you could just grab 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AppHost.Selenium.WinForms/0.1.2-beta
and build the WPF part around it by yourself. Just have a look at the sources from the WPF-package (SeleniumHost.(xaml.)cs:

https://github.com/earloc/AppHost.Selenium/tree/master/src/AppHost.Selenium.WPF